# Changing the value of a key value pair to an enviromental variable in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

```
module.exports = {
  app_uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  redirect_uri: '/redirect',

 id: 'user1',
 secret: "client_secretValue",
  ...
};
```

I have inherited the above code. I would like to change the "secret" to be read from an environment variable. I have stored it in LOCAL_SECRET and I can successfully access it through process.env.LOCAL_SECRET.

What is the correct way to add it to the value pair above? Changing it to secret:env.process.LOCAL_SECRET doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use either `dotenv` or `cross-env`.

[cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) fits pretty well if you run your scripts via `npm` or some bash script.

```
"start": "cross-env SECRET=secret && npm run server"
```

[dot-evn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) fits much better if you likes the approach of config files

1. Create a .env file in your root

   `SECRET=secret`
2. In your first script call, before any module that use your SECRET key

   `require('dotenv').config();`
3. dotenv will mix your `.env` content within your env variables.

   ```
   module.exports = {
    app_uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
     redirect_uri: '/redirect',
     id: 'user1',
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    ...
   };
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`env` is an attribute of `process`: `process.env.LOCAL_SECRET`.

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

Comment: sorry that was just a typo, you are of course correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it

```
 module.exports = {
  app_uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  redirect_uri: '/redirect',

  id: 'user1',
  secret: process.env.LOCAL_SECRET || "client_secretValue",
   ...
 };
```

OR Use dotenv node module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

You can create .env file(in project root) and add environment variables there and use it in

```
module.exports = {
  app_uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  redirect_uri: '/redirect',

  id: 'user1',
  secret: process.env.LOCAL_SECRET,
   ...
 };
```

Comment: Checking out dotenv now... the first option does not work and I receive "unhandled event"

Comment: Have you called `require('dotenv').config();` before?